# Control internet access between mobile data & WiFi in Xamarin IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, wifi, mobile-data

I am implementing an APP with Xamarin.

My APP will need to read some data from device through wifi. And send command to cloud through mobile data.

But when tested on real device. As iPhone is connected to my device through Wi-Fi and with mobile data on.

All command would transferred to device through Wi-Fi.

Is it possible for me to control the route between Wi-Fi and mobile data?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for me to control the route between Wi-Fi and mobile
> data?

You can't do that. Apple does not allow 3rd party apps to change global system settings like that. And there is no API available to control cellular data,wi-fi,bluetooth within in an app. User have to go to settings to enable or disable cellular data or wi-fi.

And when the device has both wifi and mobile data. The system will choose the wifi instead of the mobile data. And your application has no permission to change the route.